# Is there a way to run ms access applications with vba code correctly on mac?

Tags: mac, virtual-machine, vba, boot-camp, microsoft-access

I am trying to run MS Access application that includes VBA code on a mac device but unfortunately, there's no access version for mac os. So I ran windows 10 on it using bootcamp and installed ms access 2019 and the access application run correctly except that VBA code cannot run at all it! It generates an error that "the database cannot be opened because the VBA project contained in it cannot be read"

So is there a way to run MS Access applications with VBA code correctly on mac device?

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Using BootCamp on a Mac turns the Mac **into** a regular 'ol PC. The error you are seeing may be an installation issue or an issue of the file needing a (network/file?) resource that it can't find but it is almost certainly *not* because you are running Windows/Office on Mac hardware.

Comment: Thanks Steve I appreciate your comment.that's true I found the reason of that problem. It was related to windows and updating windows solved the problem.